# Stopping Simplify and FullSimplify expressing real terms as complex

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I am working with real functions but `FullSimplify` and `Simplify` express them as complex terms. I assume this is because the `LeafCount` is smaller if some real terms are expressed as complex terms.

I have been looking for an `ExcludedForms` option for `Simplify` but it does not seem to have one for making complex expressions become real.

Here is an example I am working on:

```
      rhs = -((2 L Sin[
     t ω] (Cos[α] - Cosh[α] + 
      Sin[α] Sinh[α]) F)/(α (Sin[α] - 
      Sinh[α])));
sol = q[t] /. 
   First@DSolve[{q''[t] + ωn^2 q[t] == 1/Subscript[M, n] rhs, 
      q[0] == 0, q'[0] == 0}, q[t], t];
sol2 = FullSimplify[sol]
```

With output

```
   (2 I F L (ωn Sin[t ω] - ω Sin[
     t ωn]) (Sin[(1/2 + I/2) α] - 
   Sinh[(1/2 + I/
       2) α])^2)/(α ωn (-ω + ωn) (\
ω + ωn) (Sin[α] - Sinh[α]) Subscript[M, n]
 )
```

Note the complex I's in the output

If I take the complex part and do

```
ComplexExpand[
  I (Sin[(1/2 + I/2) α] - 
     Sinh[(1/2 + I/2) α])^2 ] // Simplify
```

Then I get this real expression

```
2 (Cosh[α/2] Sin[α/2] - Cos[α/2] Sinh[α/2])^2
```

However, if I do `ComplexExpand` on the whole expression

```
ComplexExpand[sol2]
```

I get this
[image: Big expression]

and I have lost my simple form.

Is there an option for `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` that suppresses the use of complex forms? Of course if the expression were complex one would need to see the complex form.

Thanks

Comment: @chris How would you write the `ComplexityFunction` to avoid expressing real terms as complex?  The `Map` approach is an improvement; thanks.

Comment: @chris  `ComplexExpand /@ sol2`  is much better. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either write

```
ComplexExpand /@ sol2
```

[image]

or

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand /@ sol2, Trig -> False]
```

[image]

whichever you find most appropriate for your purpose.